# Creating an object which takes multiples values for a single key in swift

Tags: design-patterns, builder

How can I Have multiple value with same key?

```
{
    attribute[city][values][value][]:123
    attribute[city][values][value][]:156
    attribute[city][must_have]:1
    attribute[city][values][value][]:1
    attribute[make][must_have]:1
    attribute[make][values][value][]:45
     attribute[make][values][value][]:87
}
```

should I create own object type? In case of yes how to create such strucure?

Comment: well, most straightforward thing here is to store values in some collection. which you can get by key.
what for you need to have something like that?

Comment: This is body of a http request.I'm using alamofire for network call. The problem is i can't use dictionaries as we have multiple value with same key.What kind of collection we can use?....And is it possible to send it across alamofire request?

Comment: Wellp, I'm not familiar with that but I believe you can encdoe your dictionary or list into byte array and then you can encode it into base64 string, which you can pass

Comment: How to encode the dictionary...can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yeah .....Thanks for reply. I have created structure which contains array as one of its element